# How can I transpose this data set into this specific order?

Tags: excel, vba, transpose, excel-2016

I am using `Excel 2016` and I have a data set with 492 rows and no headers. Data starts at Cell `A1`.

An extract of the data set looks like this:

[image: extract]

I want to transpose this data set so that it becomes into this format:

[image: expected output]

I am new to `VBA` and I am having a hard time finding the right solution. I have tried recording the transpose as a `Macro` (step by step) and viewed the `VBA` codes but I still can't make it come together.

Comment: Post the code you've tried and the specific problem and then you are more likely to get help.

Comment: This is a simple **unpivot** operation.  Plenty of examples on SO using either VBA or Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, but before you do adjust the two constants at the top to match the facts on your worksheet. The worksheet with the data must be active when the code is executed.

```
Sub TransposeData()

    Const FirstDataRow As Long = 2              ' presuming row 1 has headers
    Const YearColumn As String = "A"            ' change as applicable

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant, Pos As Variant
    Dim Rl As Long, Cl As Long
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Cl = .UsedRange.Columns.Count - .UsedRange.Column + 1
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Columns(YearColumn).Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, YearColumn), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
    End With
    Arr = Rng.Value
    ReDim Pos(1 To (UBound(Arr) * UBound(Arr, 2)), 1 To 2)

    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        For C = 2 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            i = i + 1
            Pos(i, 1) = Arr(R, 1)
            Pos(i, 2) = Arr(R, C)
        Next C
    Next R

    R = Rl + 5                                  ' write 5 rows below existing data
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(R, YearColumn).Resize(i, 2)
    Rng.Value = Pos
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was needed.